# QApplication compiles with gcc 4.7 but crashes

Tags: c++, gcc4

from here http://nuwen.net/mingw.html I've downloaded gcc 4.7 and I've set this up in qt. Everything compiles fine in qt, unfortunately when I run my app (from qt) it crashes.
Any thougts?
Edit (this is this application, OS Win7, Qt 4.8):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
int main(int c, char** v)
{
    QApplication app(c,v);
    QDialog* d = new QDialog();
    d->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: @Konrad what other details would you like?

Comment: The title says QApplication doesn't compile. Your question body says the it compiles, but crashes when you run it. Which is it?

Comment: @jalf sorry about that, my mistake, app compiles but crashes

Comment: Did you recompile Qt with the new gcc version ?

Comment: @alexisdm no I didn't, I didn't know that I have to do it. I think that's the problem, would you agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update the compiler, you should probably recompile Qt.

Different version of gcc can work together, but they might be themselves compiled with incompatible options.

Comment: #alexisdm thanks, will try to do it in few weeks time then, now I'm just too busy with current project. Thanks again.